# Can't read from Twitter user stream using HTTPSConnection

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to read from my Twitter user stream using Python's `HTTPSConnection`. I can successfully connect and authorize to Twitter's API, however, nothing else is pushed to the stream when I tweet from the web site. My code is below.

```
import http.client

#Authorization headers cut
authheaders = """OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<snip>", oauth_nonce="<snip>", oauth_signature="<snip>", oauth_signature_method="<snip>", oauth_timestamp="<snip>", oauth_token="<snip>", oauth_version="1.0" """

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("userstream.twitter.com:443")
conn.putrequest("GET", "/1.1/user.json")
conn.putheader("Authorization", authheaders)
conn.endheaders()
resp = conn.getresponse()
print("HTTP " + str(resp.status))

while True:
    buff = resp.read(8192)
    if buff != b'':
        print(buff)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was reading too much data at a time. By changing `buff = resp.read(8192)` to `buff = resp.read(1024)`, I can now read my tweets.